# Issue using Bootstrap with a certain element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to use LESS and constrain Bootstrap styles to only a certain element on the page so that other elements do not get affected.

I'm displaying a Carousel on my page. When importing the LESS files outside the class like so:

```
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\variables.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\mixins.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\carousel.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\scaffolding.less";
```

I get the CSS like below for a particular class.

```
.img-responsive,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

When I use it inside the element class like so:

```
.my{
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\variables.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\mixins.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\carousel.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\scaffolding.less";
@import "..\..\..\content\bootstrap\grid.less";
}
```

I get the same CSS like below:

```
.my .img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

with the `.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img` styles stripped. Am I missing something here or is this by design? I don't want my other elements to get affected by Boostrap styles. This is also affecting how my Carousel is displayed. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Yes, your class only is affecting the responsiveness of the image. Not how the carousel is being displayed.

Comment: Thanks. How can I regain the responsiveness? Should I include another Less file for this? And why are the carousel styles being stripped?

Comment: @Alejalapeno if I do that, the styles mentioned in scaffolding.less mess with my other styles already in the page. The main css that I want is in scaffolding.less. Wrapping that as well strips some styles.

Comment: @Alejalapeno no change.

Comment: Because they're importing separately it's applying `.my` to `.img-responsive` THEN when carousel.less attempts to extend `.img-responsive` it can't because it's now `.my .img-responsive`

Comment: @Alejalapeno hm... you might be right. Any solution for this? Do I need to edit the less files. Scaffolding has tons of CSS to make changes to other elements so I'd prefer encapsulating it. That is the recommended approach I've read about in lots of blogs.

Comment: For now rather than importing you could just use the code in carousel + scaffolding. Copy+paste style. Just don't `@import` it. You might want to bring this up as an issue in the github, I use SCSS not LESS but it seems it should do all `@imports` inside the nest before including the nest. Right now it's nesting each import individually which breaks extends. (nested imports were included in the syntax in 2012, but the pull I saw for them was for a single @import so they might not have explored this use case)

Comment: @Alejalapeno Doesn't seem to work. When I include scaffolding code outside the class, it seems to get the styles right and extends carousel as well (even though carousel is within the class). Doesn't work when I include both inside. Looks like I'll have to raise this as an issue in Github... Might need to try SASS as well

Comment: I could've sworn I posted my "answer" as a comment. Did a moderator do that? I'm confused.

Comment: @Alejalapeno heh no issues. :) This is just one sample I found that didn't work. Might be more. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay well then just go the ultra simple workaround and replace line 23 in `carousel.less` `&:extend(.img-responsive);` with `&:extend(.@{my-class}.img-responsive);` and define your class as a variable so it's easier to change later.

```
@my-class: my;
.@{my-class} {
  /* your code */
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that :extend statement. Seems to work if I change it to `:extend(.my .img.responsive)`. Sort of a crappy workaround but works. So thanks :). Its pretty shocking that its hard-coded like that though...

Comment: Awesome. Doing that you should make your class a variable so that you can change it throughout without updating each instance. I updated with an example.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the tip.